# Handle exception Mono.map() function - return Mono.empty()

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a rest client that returns a json object. I have another method that calls this method and transforms the json my own object and returns that. I want to handle the scenario where the json is invalid. I think It would be best to log the issue (in my business case, I don't need to do anything else) and return a Mono.empty() but I am getting the following error:

> Required type: Mono MyPojo, Provided: Mono Object

```
public Mono<MyPojo> retrieve(String url) {
return Mono
            .from(restClient.get(url, String.class))
            .map(jsonString -> {
                try {
                    
                    return myPojoMapper.map(jsonString);
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    log.error("Exception occurred when processing message.", exception);
                    return Mono.empty()
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
public Mono<MyPojo> retrieve(String url) {
return Mono
            .from(restClient.get(url, String.class))
            .map(jsonString -> {
            try {                   
                return myPojoMapper.map(jsonString);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                log.error("Exception occurred when processing message.", exception);
            }
        }).onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty());
}
```